# Why $\alpha +\beta (|u|+|h|)(1+|u|^{p-1}+|h|^{p-1})\leq \gamma (1+|u|^p+|h|^{p})$?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

$p\geq 1$. If $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are positive constants, why is there a $\gamma>0 $ s.t for all $u,h\in \mathbb R$,
$$\alpha +\beta (|u|+|h|)(1+|u|^{p-1}+|h|^{p-1})\leq \gamma (1+|u|^p+|h|^{p})\ \ ?$$

I have this inequality in a proof, and I don't see where it come from.

Comment: Since the left hand side is a constant and $(1+|u|^p + |h|^p)$ is positive you can always choose $\gamma$ large enough to satisfy your equation. Or does this have to hold for a fixed $\gamma$ and any $u, h$ ?

Comment: yes, $\gamma $ is fixed and it's for all $u$ and $h$. I corrected it @AitorOrmazabal

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to assume your result and find an appropriate $\gamma$. Note this would give on the left side
$\alpha\frac{1}{1+|u|^p+|h|^p}+\beta\frac{(1+|u|^{p-1}+|h|^{p-1})(|u|+|h|)}{1+|u|^p+|h|^p}$. Note that fraction associated with $\alpha$ has a maximum of 1, and the fraction associated with $\beta$ is rational function which is defined for all $u,h$ and which approaches 1 for large $|u|,|h|$, and is therefore bounded. Hence there is some constant $k$ for which $\gamma=\alpha+k\beta$ will satisfy the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose WLOG that $|u|\leq |v|.$ Using the fact that $1+|u|^p+|v|^p\geq 1+|v|^p$, we get

$$\frac{\alpha +\beta (|u|+|v|)(1+|u|^{p-1}+|v|^{p-1})}{\gamma (1+|u|^p+|v^p|)}\leq \frac{\alpha +2|v|(1+2|v|^{p-1})}{\gamma (1+|v|^p)}=\frac{\alpha +2|v|+4|v|^p}{\gamma (1+|v|^p)}\underset{|v|\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }\frac{4}{\gamma }.$$

The claim follow.